# Why this indefinite integral cannot be solved ?$\int\ln(x)\sqrt{x^{2 }+ ax + b}\, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to find a solution to this integral. However I have found nothing
that helps, even wolfram alpha can not solve this integral. What would be
the secret about it, since it looks so simple ?

indefinite integral:

$\int \ln(x)\sqrt{x^{2 }+ ax + b}\, dx$

Anyone has a guess ?

Comment: Maybe Wolfram Alpha has nothing to say because the integral cannot be performed in terms of standard functions?

Comment: Isnt this wierd ? I mean, maybe a solution in a form of hypergeometric function or special function, but I get nothing

Comment: What's weird about that?

Comment: The wierd thing is that I can solve it easily by using Gauss integration, but I needed an analytic solution

Comment: In fact, most integrals do not have closed form.

Comment: http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/IntegralsIndefinite/IndefInt.html

Comment: Harry Peter thank you very much for your answer. In that page it seems that there is a result where my parameter "b = 1", do you have any idea on how Prof. Dieckman solved those integrals ?